# Parsing data from CSV file

Tags: c#, csv

Like in title I have problem with parsing data from CVS files. When i choose file with diffrent formating all i get is "Input string was not in a correct format". 
My code works with files formatted like that:

```
16.990750 4.0
17.000250 5.0
17.009750 1.0
17.019250 6.0
```

But cant handle files formatted like this one:

```
Series1 - X;Series1 - Y;
285.75;798
285.79;764
285.84;578
285.88;690
```

This is code responsibile for reading data from file and creating chart from it:

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string cos = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            string[] rows = cos.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("xValue", typeof(decimal));
            table.Columns.Add("yValue", typeof(decimal));

            foreach (string row in rows)
            {
                string[] values = row.Split(' ');
                DataRow ch = table.NewRow();
                ch[0] = Decimal.Parse(values[0], NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                ch[1] = Decimal.Parse(values[1], NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                table.Rows.Add(ch);

            }
            if (seria == false)
            {
                wykres.Series.Add("series");
                wykres.Series["series"].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
                wykres.Series["series"].XValueMember = "xValue";
                wykres.Series["series"].YValueMembers = "yValue";
                wykres.DataSource = table;
                wykres.DataBind();

                seria = true;



            }
         }
```

EDIT

I changed parsing method to this one:

```
                foreach (string row in rows)
            {
                var values = row.Split(';');
                var ch = table.NewRow();
                decimal num = 0;
                if (decimal.TryParse(values[0], out num))
                    ch[0] = num;
                if (decimal.TryParse(values[1], out num))
                    ch[1] = num;
                table.Rows.Add(ch);
            }
```

It works okay but with one exception - It can't read decimals only integers from csv file(see the picture below).

[View of table in locals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ztk23.png)

Why is this happening?

Comment: Just change that one line that splits the row on spaces to splitting it on semi-colons: `string[] values = row.Split(';');`

Comment: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

Comment: did u look with a debugger at the content of `values` after splitting the line

Comment: Btw. you can use [`File.ReadAllLines()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) to split the content already while reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you don't re-invent the wheel, but use some well-tested library to parse the CSV (for example, your implementation does not handle quoted values well. It also doesn't allow the separator as part of a value).

And guess what: .NET includes something that could help you: the [TextFieldParser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. Don't worry about the `VisualBasic`namespace - it works in C#, too :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (string row in rows)
            {
                var values = row.Split(';');
                var ch = table.NewRow();
                decimal num = 0;
                if (decimal.TryParse(values[0], out num))
                    ch[0] = num;
                if (decimal.TryParse(values[1], out num))
                    ch[1] = num;
                table.Rows.Add(ch);
            }
```

In the second text format the separator is(;) and first row of the text has two strings therefore to convert a string to decimal use decimal.TryParse() instead of decimal.Parse().the return type of method TryParse() is boolean
therefore if it returned true that means the string converted successful .

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: @CodeCaster I have problem with this solution. I don't know why but every integer is parsed from file properly but decimals are ignored. [image of what is kept in table from locals](http://i.imgur.com/Hs99Iau.png).